# Cudo installation error 1

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

When I try to install cudo with the instructions on their website - https://www.cudominer.com/miner-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04/, I recieve the following error message, and despite trying to follow advice here: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1, I've been unable to fix it.

The error message:

```bsh
Unpacking cudo-miner-desktop (1.0.5) ...
Setting up cudo-miner-core (1.1.4) ...
Setting up cudo-miner-service (1.1.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package cudo-miner-service (--configure):
 installed cudo-miner-service package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cudo-miner-desktop:
 cudo-miner-desktop depends on cudo-miner-service (= 1.1.4); however:
  Package cudo-miner-service is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cudo-miner-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cudo-miner-service
 cudo-miner-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and could not find a solution specifically for cudo-miner. However, after a bit of hit and trial, the following steps worked for me without any further trouble.

1. Use the installation command from cudo miner website to start the installation. Answer the questions and move forward with the installation. It will finish the execution and throw the aforementioned error.
2. Now run the following set of commands.

```bsh
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/cudo-*
sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 cudo-miner-service
sudo apt -f install
```

All the `cudo-miner*` packages should be correctly installed now.